# How To Add List Elements and Convert Them To A String

Tags: python, list, dictionary, reduce

I am attempting to write a function that turns a string of lower case letters into a string of all capital letter. I'm trying to use reduce and map() to do this, though a list comprehension instead of map would be alright too.

Comment: Would using `string.upper()` be an option, or do you need to do this on your own?

Comment: Your `all_caps` function has two return statements.  Only the first on will be executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str.upper()`:

```
>>> 'How are you?'.upper()
'HOW ARE YOU?'
```

Regarding your question "I can't figure out how to put them back together from the list into strings", use `str.join`:

```
>>> lis = ['H', 'O', 'W', ' ', 'A', 'R', 'E', ' ', 'Y', 'O', 'U', '?']
>>> ''.join(lis)
'HOW ARE YOU?'
```

If you want to use `reduce`, you need to give it an initial value of `''` and give it a function that takes two arguments and reduces them to a single result:

```
>>> reduce(lambda s,t:s + t, lis, '')
'HOW ARE YOU?'
```

`reduce` without `lambda`:

```
>>> import operator
>>> reduce(operator.add, lis, '')
'HOW ARE YOU?'
```

**important note**:  Using `reduce` to build a string is *very inefficient* because it creates a new string after each addition.  The performance for even medium length strings would be excessive.

Comment: Your add function would need to take two strings and return one.  `def add_s(s, t):return s + t`.  Or use `operator.add`.